# count() parameter must be an array or an object when there is no record in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeignator, I have a function in the model which is

```
function getList()
    {
$result = $this->db->where(['members.member_type'=>1,'members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1])
    ->order_by("members.member_id", "desc")
    ->from('members')
    ->join('admin_users','admin_users.admin_user_id = members.created_by')
    ->get()
    ->result();
        if($result)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Above code, I am using to display the all the list on view page which is working. Now I have one more view page and I am displaying the total number of the users using the same code. So I added the code

```
$data['primary_data'] = count($this->List_model->getList());
print_r($data['primary_data']);
```

It's also working but when there are no records then I am getting the error

```
count() parameter must be an array or an object that implements countable in codeigniter
```

Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's $this->db->result() method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.

Just return the result as it is. If there are results it will return an array of objects. If no result found, it will return an empty array. So the counting on the result will work all the time.

```
function getList() {
  return $this->db->where(['members.member_type'=>1,'members.is_Approved'=>1,'members.is_status'=>1])
    ->order_by("members.member_id", "desc")
    ->from('members')
    ->join('admin_users','admin_users.admin_user_id = members.created_by')
    ->get()
    ->result();
}
```

Comment: Oh! Yes, it's correct, It's working if there are no records in the database. give me some time to insert the data

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty array instead of `0` in getList() method.

```
return [];
```

can write this:

```
return $result ? $result : [];
```